# Фильтр и группировка не работают вместе на яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как заставить работать geoQuery и objectManager вместе?

Сейчас у меня выводятся и группируются метки из JSON.

```
      url: "/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/news.list/map_new/data.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(response) {
         objectManager.add(response);
           console.log(response)
```

Добавил фильтр и теперь получаю метки так:

```
      jQuery.getJSON('/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/news.list/map_new/data.php', function (json) {
           window.myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(json)
               .addToMap(myMap3)
       })
```

Но проблема в том, что первым методом все группируется, но не срабатывает фильтр. А вторым срабатывает фильтр, но не работает группировка. Можно ли их вообще как то совместить?

Полный код:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap3 = new ymaps.Map('map3', {
      center: [55.76, 37.64],
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
      clusterize: true,
      gridSize: 32,
      clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });



  objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
  objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
  myMap3.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

  jQuery.getJSON('/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/news.list/map_new/data.php', function(json) {
    window.myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(json)
      .addToMap(myMap3)
  })



  function checkState() {
    var shownObjects,
      quantity = $('#quantity').val(),
      city = $('#city').val(),
      location = $('#location').val(),
      filter_c = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult(),
      filter_l = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult(),
      filter_q = new ymaps.GeoQueryResult();

    var variant = 0;

    if (quantity != null) {
      variant += 1;
    }
    if (city != null) {
      variant += 10;
    }
    if (location != null) {
      variant += 100;
    }

    switch (variant) {
      case 1:
        filter_q = myObjects.search('options.quantity="' + quantity + '"').add(filter_q);
        shownObjects = filter_q.addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
      case 10:
        filter_c = myObjects.search('options.city="' + city + '"').add(filter_c);
        shownObjects = filter_c.addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
      case 100:
        filter_l = myObjects.search('options.location="' + location + '"').add(filter_l);
        shownObjects = filter_l.addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
      case 11:
        filter_q = myObjects.search('options.quantity="' + quantity + '"').add(filter_q);
        filter_c = myObjects.search('options.city="' + city + '"').add(filter_c);
        shownObjects = filter_c.intersect(filter_q).addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
      case 101:
        filter_q = myObjects.search('options.quantity="' + quantity + '"').add(filter_q);
        filter_l = myObjects.search('options.location="' + location + '"').add(filter_l);
        shownObjects = filter_l.intersect(filter_q).addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
      case 110:
        filter_l = myObjects.search('options.location="' + location + '"').add(filter_l);
        filter_c = myObjects.search('options.city="' + city + '"').add(filter_c);
        shownObjects = filter_c.intersect(filter_l).addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
      case 111:
        filter_q = myObjects.search('options.quantity="' + quantity + '"').add(filter_q);
        filter_l = myObjects.search('options.location="' + location + '"').add(filter_l);
        filter_c = myObjects.search('options.city="' + city + '"').add(filter_c);
        shownObjects = filter_c.intersect(filter_l).intersect(filter_q).addToMap(myMap3);
        break;
    }

    myObjects.remove(shownObjects).removeFromMap(myMap3);
  }

  $('#city').change(checkState);
  $('#location').change(checkState);
  $('#quantity').change(checkState);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <select id="city">
      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Город:</option>
      <option value="Москва">Москва</option>
      <option value="Пермь">Пермь</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="location">
      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Улица:</option>
      <option value="Гагарина">Гагарина</option>
      <option value="Пушкина">Пушкина</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="quantity">
      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Количество домов:</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="map3" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, достаточно просто добавить объекты Менеджера в geoQuery:

```
ymaps.geoQuery(objectManager.objects)
```

Но не нужно :) потому objectManager сам умеет фильтровать объекты по options через [setFilter()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager.html#method_detail__setFilter). У Яндекса есть [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter/).

А в geoQuery можно [включить кластеризацию](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html#method_detail__clusterize).
[Пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/apply_bounds_and_clusterize) тоже есть.